# Create "grid-like" row and column selector for table generator

Tags: javascript, html, css, figma-plugin

I am creating a Figma plugin that generates table according to user's preferences.
UI of plugin is in pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

So far I have a simple UI with range inputs that look like this for choosing how many columns and rows user wants in the table:

[image]

Code:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Dimensions</legend>
  <p>
    <label for="countRows">Number of Rows:</label> 
    <input class="range" id="countRows" name="countRows" type="range" value="3" min="0" max="10" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
    <output>3</output>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="countColumns">Number of Columns:</label> 
    <input class="range" id="countColumns" name="countColumns" type="range" value="5" min="1" max="10" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
    <output>5</output>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

I am looking for a "grid-like" solution on choosing how many rows and columns table should have, similar to what Microsoft Word has:

[image]

Do you have any hints where to find more info about this type of solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is preventing you from coding it yourself?

Comment: @tacoshy does it have a specific name, by which I could find the libraries of which it is a part, or some ready-made solutions? I haven't tried anything yet because it seems too complex to me and design is not a plugin priority, so I wanted to know if anyone has any tips on what and where to look

Comment: asking for anything like that is against the SO rules. But literally you can easily code it yourself by using CSS grid and many single elements such as buttons

Comment: @tacoshy that's a misunderstanding. I meant if it is as common as just changing type="" in input to just have that grid, or similarly easy solution. I don't want anyone to stack 100 divs with 100 buttons for me...